# How can XSLT change a part of a node name?

Tags: xml, xslt

I would like to create an XSLT that wil change  the name of all elements in my XML files by converting the dots in the names to underscores. There’s lots of information on changing the full name of an element, but not on replacing a part of the name. How should I set up my XSLT?

The following XML file has to be transformed into a table tblPerson:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<DB>
   <person>
      <person.id id="P000072">
      <person.last_name>Drukker</person.last_name>
      <person.first_name>Bernard</person.first_name>
      <person.d_birth>1910-01-01</person.d_birth>
      <person.place_birth>Amsterdam</person.place_birth>
      <person.d_death>1992-12-13</person.d_death>
      <person.place_death>Velp</person.place_death>
   </person>
</DB>
```

Next shows how the output of the transformation should look like. The dot “.” has to be converted to an underscore “_”  .

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<DB>
  <tblPerson>
  <person_id>P000072</person_id>
  <person_last_name>Drukker</person_last_name>
  <person_first_name>Bernard</person_first_name>
  <person_d_birth>1910-01-01</person_d_birth>
  <person_place_birth>Amsterdam</person_place_birth>
  <person_d_death>1992-12-13</person_d_death>
  <person_place_death>Velp</person_place_death>
  </tblPerson>
</DB>
```

I hope that the same code can be applied to other nodes with a different name but a similar dot feature. Your suggestions will be appreciated greatly.

Karel

Comment: Your input document is not well-formed XML. The XML declaration should end with `?>` and this: `<person.id="P000072">` is neither a valid element nor attribute.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Write a template

```
<xsl:template match="*[contains(local-name(), '.')]">
  <xsl:element name="{translate(local-name(), '.', '_')}" namespace="{namespace-uri()}">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
  </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>
```

which manipulates the name, then use a template

`<xsl:template match="person"><tblPerson><xsl:apply-templates/></tblPerson></xsl:template>`

to change the name of the `person` element and then add the identity transformation template

```
<xsl:template match="@* | node()">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

to make sure the rest is copied unchanged.

Comment: You forgot the part where he wants to wrap the `person*` elements into `<tblPerson>`

Comment: You are right, I have added a template to fix that problem.

Comment: @Martin Honnen - your answer came faster than lightning. Fabulous! Thank you very much. Now I can see that my brackets were everywhere but in the right place. Your code will bring me back on the right track to write the rest of a rather lengthy XSLT. The addition of the person elements is also very helpful.